# How to count the number of times in a pandas df that the sum of consecutive values crosses a threshold?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame that consists of a time-series of integers.  I'm trying to group the data frame by year and then for each year count the number of times that the sum of the absolute value of consecutive entries with the same sign is greater than or equal to 5.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> l  = [1, -1, -4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1, -3, -4]
>>> idx1 = pd.date_range('2019-01-01',periods=5)
>>> idx2 = pd.date_range('2020-01-01',periods=5)
>>> idx = idx1.union(idx2)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(l, index=idx, columns=['a'])
>>> df
            a
2019-01-01  1
2019-01-02 -1
2019-01-03 -4 \\ 2019 count = 1: abs(-1) + abs(-4) >= 5
2019-01-04  2
2019-01-05  2
2020-01-01  4
2020-01-02  5 \\ 2020 count = 1: abs(4) + abs(5) + abs(1) = 10 >=5 
2020-01-03  1
2020-01-04 -3
2020-01-05 -4 \\ 2020 count = 2: abs(-3) + abs(-4) = 7 >= 5
```

The desired output is:

```
2019 1
2020 2
```

My approach to solve this problem is to chain `groupby` and `apply`.  Below are the implementations of the functions I created to pass to `groupby` and `apply` respectively.

```
>>> def get_year(x):
        return x.year

>>> def count(group, t=5):
        c = 0 # counter
        s = 0 # sum of consec vals w same sign                                                    
        for i in range(1,len(group)):
            if np.sign(group['a'].iloc[i-1]) == np.sign(group['a'].iloc[i]): 
                if s == 0:
                    s = group['a'].iloc[i-1] + group['a'].iloc[i]
                else:
                    s += group['a'].iloc[i]
                if i == (len(group) -1):
                   return c + 1
            elif (np.sign(group['a'].iloc[i-1]) != np.sign(group['a'].iloc[i])) and (abs(s) >= t):
    #if consec streak of vals w same sign is broken and abs(s) >= t then inc c and reset s
                c += 1
                s = 0
            elif (np.sign(group['a'].iloc[i-1]) != np.sign(group['a'].iloc[i])) and (abs(s) < t):
    #if consec streak of vals w same sign is broken and abs(s) < t then reset s
                s = 0
     return c

>>> by_year = df.groupby(get_year)
>>> by_year.apply(count)
2019 1
2020 2
```

My question is:
Is there a more "pythonic" implementation of the above `count` function that produces the desired result but doesn't rely on `for` loops?

Comment: Are you asking what the signature of the function that you pass to `by_year.apply` should be, or are you asking for a complete implementation of such a function? Remember that your question is likely to be received better by the community if it contains your attempt at solving the problem as a [mre], and a specific question about it -- where do you think your logic is going wrong? Did you come up with any logic? If not, try writing down the steps to solve this problem on paper, then implement those steps in your function. See [ask] and [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks for the suggestions.  I came up with an implementation and included the function in the edit of my question.  Would you recommend I close the question and repost it as a new question to increase visibility?

Comment: Much better! No, don't close and repost it. Editing your question already bumped it to the top of the front page. I'll take a look and try to answer later today.